# How to select convert and sum from database?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a column price datatype is nvarchar because I save thousand seperator with comma like 1,000,000.00. I now need to select convert and sum it in select statement then display group by id in **crystalreport**.

My select statement:

```
select id,productname,type,price,datesell,seller from tb_billdetail group by id
```

Here I need how to convert the price from nvarchar to type double and sum it after converted but just using select statement?

Something I need to display in crystal report like:

```
col_id     col_name     col_type     col_price     col_date 

**001**


001        fish         food          20,000.00    01/02/2018     
001        fish         food          10,000.00    10/02/2018
```

col_sum id 001:   30,000.00

next group  id 002 and 003 ....

Comment: Choosing to store a value as the display value instead of the raw value is always a bad idea.  Store it as a decimal, problem solved.

Comment: Don't store it with the commas - store it as a numeric type and add the commas when you _display_ the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @tt table (name nvarchar(10), value nvarchar(10))
insert into @tt (name, value) values ('a', '1,000')
insert into @tt (name, value) values ('a', '1,10,000')
insert into @tt (name, value) values ('b', '2,000.4223')
insert into @tt (name, value) values ('b', '4,000.2')

select name, sum(cast(REPLACE(value,',','') as float)) as sum from @tt group by name
```

it's not a good idea to store with comma separate, store it's as the decimal.
If your storing comma for displaying purpose then add it when displaying.

Comment: it is possible to select more columns because when I select more columns it gives me in error. Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'tb_product.type' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: you should add all column in the group by other than aggregate function in SQL Server